# How to set AVAudioUnitEQ equalizer presets gain values for 10 frequency bands in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, equalizer, preset

I could add an audio setup to change equalizer by changing slider values by

```
let FREQUENCY: [Float] = [31, 62, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000]
//let FREQUENCY: [Float] = [60, 230, 910, 3600, 14000]

self.audioEngine = AVAudioEngine.init()
self.audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode.init()
self.audioUnitEQ = AVAudioUnitEQ(numberOfBands: 10)
self.audioEngine.attach(self.audioPlayerNode)
self.audioEngine.attach(self.audioUnitEQ)        

for i in 0...9 {
    self.audioUnitEQ.bands[i].filterType = .parametric
    self.audioUnitEQ.bands[i].frequency = FREQUENCY[i]
    self.audioUnitEQ.bands[i].bandwidth = 0.5 // half an octave
    let eq = self.value(forKey: String(format: "eq%d", i)) as! UISlider
    self.audioUnitEQ.bands[i].gain = eq.value
    self.audioUnitEQ.bands[i].bypass = false
}
```

But Is there any method to change gain values or set equalizer presets like Accoustics, Rock etc. How to set their gain values for those presets

Comment: Did you ever find anything about this?  I'm also looking to change the acoustics for five different venue types with presets for ["Large room (hard surfaces)", "Large room (soft surfaces)", "Small room (hard surfaces)", "Small room (soft surfaces)", "Outdoors"].